# React external CSS doesn't work on section tag

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a simple `<section>` with a `<h1>` tag inside it.

```
<section className = "topone">
        <h1>Test Text</h1>
</section>
```

Inline .css works fine, but I want to use an external .css file, I have `stylish.css` as like below;

```
.topone {
    background-color : "white";
    display: 'flex';
    justify-content:'center';
    align-items:'center';
    width : '100vw';
}
```

in .js, I'm using it like this;

**foo.js**

```
import './stylish.css';

const Test = () => {
    return (
    
    <>
    <section className = "topone">
        <h1>Test Text</h1>
    </section>
    </>
     )
}
export default Test
```

But this doesn't affect at all. Nothing has been changed. I've tried similar solutions to this problem but still it doesn't work, only inline css works.

What am I missing here and why it doesn't work?

**Edit:** foo.js is actually calling from a Router, so in my App.js I'm using a Router to foo.js when a condition occurs. And there are other .css imports in those .js files, is it related to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem, first I thought this is related to 3rd library 'react-toastify' because it also imports it's own .css file. But the problem was in my own .css file.

1. Assigning the .css file to a variable like `import style from './styles.css'` **doesn't work at all**. It only accepts `import './styles.css'` and using `className` corresponding in .css file.
2. In .css file, I have removed all quotes.

So .css file looks like this now

**style.css**

```
.topone {
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

Using it in foo.js like this;

**foo.js**

```
import './style.css'

//codes

<section className = "topone" />
```

solved the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Are you sure that you use the correct import path? If you keep your styles in a different folder you may want to include them like this:

import '../stylesFolder/stylish.css';

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.